# Не получается запустить сервер Minecraft версии 1.17.1 на виртуальной машине с CentOS

Tags: java, сервер, centos, centos7, minecraft

Ошибка:

> A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/minecraft/server/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

[image: выдает эту ошибку с java 1.8.0]

Пробовал разные версии Java 11 1.6.0 1.7.0 1.8.0

С другими версиями примерно то же самое, но version up to не 52, а меньше

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/nv92fg/error_while_launcher_a_117_minecraft_server_fix/

Comment: теперь всплыла другая ошибка, не получается разархивировать **tar xzvf jdk-16.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz**  пишет - tar: для старой опции f нужно указать аргумент.

Comment: Вы вручную разархивируете?

Comment: а можно как то по другому? (я просто совсем не давно начал работать с centos 7)

Comment: `tar -xzvf jdk-16.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`

Comment: так я так и делал

Comment: Вы делали так: `tar xzvf jdk-16.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz`

Comment: извиняюсь, сработало